# an object reference is required for non static method or property 'System.Web.MVC.ControllerContext.Controller.get'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a class in my asp.net MVC 3 application's Model folder and using the following code in it

```
   var controller = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
```

but it is underlined and says: an object reference is required for non static method or property

> 'System.Web.MVC.ControllerContext.Controller.get'

how to get rid of this error.

Below is full code:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var user = (CreditRegistryPrincipal)filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (!user.IsAdminAuthorized)
            {
                var controller = System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { 
                    { "controller", "Admin" }, 
                    { "action", "adfdsf" } 
                });
            }
        }
```

Regards,
Asif

Comment: What are you doing with var controller?  It doesn't look like you ever use it anywhere in the rest of your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var controller = System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```

isn't syntactically valid, so I'd expect a different compilation error (; expected).

Not sure why you're trying to access ViewContext inside a model, though. Presumably, it's actually a custom authorization attribute?

Have you tried:

```
var controller = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```

or

```
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controller = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the filtercontext that is passed to the OnAuthorization function.  So you should be able to change this:

```
var controller = System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```

To This:

```
var controller = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;
```